# Fluentd log collector from file

Tags: apache, fluentd

I need to collect the data from data file, which is created by application.
Log file is located in "/var/log/payment-service.log". The application is running in 9100 port.

I have added configuration in /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf. Configuration is below

```
# Receive events from 24224/tcp
# This is used by log forwarding and the fluent-cat command
<source>
  @type forward
  port 9100
</source>

# http://this.host:9880/myapp.access?json={"event":"data"}
<source>
  @type http
  port 9880
</source>
```

I have tried to get logs from rest calls like this

```
http://localhost:9880/myapp.access?json={event:data}
```

But I could't get any result from that url.

Please help anyone to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [in_tail plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/in_tail) to read your log file "/var/log/payment-service.log".

```
<source>
  @type tail
  path /var/log/payment-service.log
  pos_file /tmp/payment-service.log.pos
  tag payment-service.log
  <parse>
    # parse your logs
  </parse>
</source>

<match payment-service.log>
  @type stdout
</match>
```

You cannot use [in_forward plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/categories/in_forward) to read your log files, and you can not use [in_http plugin](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/categories/in_http) to fetch your logs from Fluentd.

Please read linked documents carefully.